# Linq to SQL get multiple columns

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am developing an asp.net MVC web app in which I am using Linq to Sql for getting the results from database through jquery and ajax. My model has following code

```
 public IEnumerable<string> getComments(long problemID)
        {

            var comment = from c in _objectModel.Comments
                          where c.ProblemID == problemID
                          select new { c.EmpID, c.CommentText, c.Time }.ToString();

            return comment;

        }
```

and my controller has following code

```
public string GetComments(string problemid)
        {
            List<string> collection =  _discussionRepository.getComments(Convert.ToInt32(problemid)).ToList();
            string comments = null;
            foreach (string item in collection)
            {
                comments += item + "\n";

            }

            return comments; 



        }
```

and in my view contains

```
$("#btnPostComment").click(function () {
  var strdata = {
           problemID: $("#problemID").val(),
           commentText: $("#_1").val(),
           empID: $("#empID").val(),
           agree: 0,
           disagree: 0
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<%= Url.Action("PostComment", "Discussion")  %>",
            data: strdata,
  error: function(msg){
                alert("error" + msg);
            },
            success: function (msg) {
                var id = { problemid :  $("#problemID").val()};
                 $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "<%= Url.Action("GetComments", "Discussion")  %>",
                    data:  id,
                    error: function(msg){
                         alert("error2" + msg);
                    },
                    success: function (msg) {

                        $("#commentdiv").html(msg);
                    }
                    });


            }
        });
```

and I am getting the following result in my asp page

{ EmpID = 1, CommentText = sss, Time = 1/27/2012 2:20:49 AM } { EmpID = 1, CommentText = aaa, Time = 1/27/2012 2:46:07 AM } { EmpID = 1, CommentText = aaa, Time = 1/27/2012 2:50:23 AM } { EmpID = 1, CommentText = Munazza, Time = 1/27/2012 2:58:29 AM } { EmpID = 1, CommentText = Jawad, Time = 1/27/2012 3:00:51 AM } { EmpID = 1, CommentText = xx, Time = 1/28/2012 11:56:59 AM } { EmpID = 1, CommentText = ss, Time = 1/28/2012 12:35:00 PM }

I want to get the result without braces and without properties i.e 1 ss 1/27/2012

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're calling `ToString` on the anonymous type. Does your existing `Comment` model class contain too much data? If not, you can just use:

```
public List<Comment> GetComments(long problemID)
{
    return _objectModel.Comments.Where(c => c.ProblemID == problemID)
                                .ToList(); // Force evaluation
}
```

You'd then change your controller to convert this `List<Comment>` into AJAX which the Javascript could understand.

If you *really* only want strings without properties, you could just change your original code to:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetComments(long problemID)
{
    var query = from c in _objectModel.Comments
                where c.ProblemID == problemID
                select new { c.EmpID, c.CommentText, c.Time };

    return query.AsEnumerable() // Do the rest locally
                .Select(c => string.Format("{0} {1} {2"}, c.EmpID,
                                           c.CommentText, c.Time));
}
```

You should *also* change your controller code to either use `String.Join` or a `StringBuilder` - as otherwise you're going to have an O(n<sup>2</sup>) problem due to repeated string concatenation...

Comment: Please tell me the code of controller for sending string to the view

Comment: @Snake: Pass, I'm afraid - I haven't done any ASP.NET MVC. Presumably you don't actually *want* it in the view directly, but made available via an AJAX call. It feels like you may currently be in slightly over your head - how many of these technologies are new to you? I find it works best if I only try to learn *one* new thing at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your client-side code it seems you're expecting formatted html from the ajax call, but you're simply returing ToString (as Jon Skeet says).

If this is your intent then you should format the string into valid HTML, but it would be better to return the data in json format and turn it into HTML client-side.

Comment: I should add that the whole idea of MVC is to seperate concerns. So presenting the data to the user is the concern of the view. So, you shouldn't really be returning formatted HTML from the controller.